# local intersection multiplicity

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading *kenji uneo*گس book on *algebraic geometry 1*. I don't understand how to compute the local intersection multiplicity. I would appreciate if you can show me how to compute it for the next two curves. $f=y-2x ,g=y^2-x^2(x+1)$.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I've searched the net, and found a nice coverage of how to calculate the local intersection multiplicity, here:
http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~gm/teaching/MATH32062/intmult.pdf

But I still don't see from this how to calculate for example the local intersection multiplicity at the origin of the two curves:

$$f= y^2-x^3 ; g= y^2-x^2(x+1)$$

There seems to be only an algorithm for when one equation is linear and the other isn't linear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you provided missed out two properties of the intersection number, which are all I've ever used to calculate intersection numbers!

1) $I_P(F,G)\geq m_P(F)m_P(G)$ with equality if $F,G$ have no common tangent. $m_P$ is the multiplicity of the curve at $P$.

2) $I_P(F,G) = I_P(F,G+AF),\ A\in k[X,Y]$

Creative use of these two rules usually works. Use 2) until you have no common tangents, then apply 1).

In your case, $F=Y^2-X^3$ and $G=Y^2-X^2(X+1)$ The least degree homogeneous components are $F_2 = Y^2$ and $G_2=Y^2-X^2=(Y-X)(X+Y)$ so $F,G$ have no common tangents at the origin, and therefore $I_P(F,G) = m_P(F)m_P(G) = 2\cdot 2 = 4$.

Comment: In the answers in the book its written that the answer is 5.

Comment: It simply states it is 5? I am quite certain the correct answer is 4. If you look at the plots of these curves (not always a good idea, but these are simple enough) you can see the 4 intersections we expect (the X axis is counted as a tangent twice). There is no conceivable way of having a 5th intersection!

Comment: Yes. Which book has the exact and readable techniques to use for computing the local intersection multiplicty and most importantly with the explanation of why do we use these techniques from the definition of local intersection multiplicty?

Comment: I learnt from William Fulton's Algebraic Curves. It is freely available online. A quote from page 40, "Second, the proof shows that the calculation of intersection numbers is a
very easy matter. Making imaginative use of (5) and (7) can save much time, but the
proof shows that nothing more is needed than some arithmetic with polynomials."